# As i defining feature as below it was not working.i just want to know where is the error and can i use two scenario outline in the same feature file

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

i am new to cucumber frame work just i want know about how to use

As i defining feature as below it was not working.i just want to know where is the error and can i use two scenario outline in the same feature file

```
Scenario Outline: Checkout descriptions
   Given I am logged in as "<user>"
     And I have gone to the checkout after selecting various products
   When I purchase the items
   Then I should be able to checkout <with?> a description

 Examples:
   | user  | with?   |
   | Arun  | with    |
   | Ajay  | with    |
   | Ashok | with    |
   | Arun  | without |
   | Ajay  | without |
   | Ashok | without |

Scenario Outline: Checkout with description and accept the terms of service*
   Given I am logged in as "<user>"
     And I have gone to the checkout after selecting various products
   When I purchase the items
   Then I should be able to checkout with a description
     And I should be able to accept the terms of service*

 Examples:
   | user  |
   | Arun  |
   | Ajay  |
   | Ashok |
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's your entire feature file, then you're missing one line from the top:

```
Feature: Checkout Descriptions

   Scenario Outline: Checkout Descriptions
    ...
```

Cucumber cannot parse a feature file with no `Feature` / `Business Need` / `Ability` in the top line.

Comment: Yes, the **Feature** keyword is missing and we can use multiple **Scenario Outline** in a single Feature file.